Use Azure DevOps in Microsoft Loop
My organization uses Azure DevOps and Microsoft Loop (which is a Microsoft tool). We are all in on the Microsoft tools. Can I connect my Azure DevOps components to MS Loop in the same way that I connect Jira (and Jira and Github, AND planner? The Azure DevOps and Loop use the same Microsoft account.
I tried to integrate them following this instruction provided by Microsoft Support, but I cannot find Azure DevOps in the app menus in Loop
https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/use-ado-with-loop-713861e2-cfcc-4c13-8c04-8f08fc5d41c6
Is there anything I need to do first? or missed some step?

Hi @GuanlinCao, Welcome to SO. Would you please let us know if the query in this post can be resolved by the answer below by Arko? Thx for your time and sharing.

Although this MS doc shows connection steps but currently, there is no direct integration or official sync between Azure DevOps and Microsoft Loop, but there are several workarounds to connect the two and make use of their combined functionality.
I cross checked,


This doesn't seem to be the full integration you are expecting for pulling in work items or queries directly into Loop.
As a work around you can try-

Manual Integration i.e. you can copy links to relevant ADO items (such as work items, boards, and pipelines) and paste them into Loop components like notes or tables, providing easy access and reference within your collaborative workspace or capture screenshots of important ADO information and embed them in Loop components.

Use Third-Party Solutions such as Power Automate to trigger actions in ADO based on events in Loop (for instance, creating a work item when a task in Loop is completed). This helps automate workflows and ensures data remains synced across both platforms.



Reference- Read this MS Support Ticket
